# Will the indices law of $ a^m \times a^n = a^{(m+n)}$ hold true if $a$ equals the constant e and m and n are imaginary?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Our A-Level textbook gives an example where given complex numbers $z_1,z_2$, it was proven that $|z_1z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$ and that $arg(z_1z_2) = arg(z_1) + arg(z_2)$.
This is done by considering the complex numbers in the form of $r(cos\theta+isin\theta)$

$z_1z_2=r_1(cos\theta_1+isin\theta_1)r_2(cos\theta_2+isin\theta_2)$ which when expanded and invoking the addition formulae for sin and cos yields

$r_1r_2[cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)+i(sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)]$

This completes the proof.

It then continues by saying if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are written in exponential form $r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ respectively, **based on the results from above,**

$z_1z_2=r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$

It then displays a Watch Out message that says

"You cannot automatically assume the law of indices work the same way with complex numbers as with real numbers. This results only shows that they can be applied in these specific cases"

I am confused by the last sentence. Do they mean that $z_1z_2=r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$ is fortuitous? That it is not a result of applying the law of indices?

I guess my question is, is it true, for $\theta, \beta\;real $, invoking the indices law for real numbers that

$e^{i\theta}\times e^{i\beta}=e^{i(\theta+\beta)}?$

Comment: Use the angle sum identities for sine and cosine.

Comment: amended. Thanks @AnneBauval

Comment: More generally, $$\forall u,v\in\Bbb C,\;\forall a\in\Bbb R_+,\;a^ua^v=a^{u+v}.$$ But it is indeed "not a result of applying the law of indices", which only tells you that $$\forall m,n\in\Bbb Z,\;\forall z\in\Bbb C^*,\;z^mz^n=z^{m+n}.$$

Comment: In general, we do have $z^{w_1}z^{w_2} = z^{w_1+w_2}$ for any complex numbers $z,w_1,w_2$ with $z\neq 0$; but we have to prove it.  It isn't immediate.  In contrast, $(z^{w_1})^{w_2} = z^{w_1w_2}$ is often false, even though your intuition from real numbers might cause you to think otherwise.

Comment: The expression $a^z$ in general is multi-valued in the complex numbers.  However, there is a nice function $\exp(z)$ that is single-valued, and selects one preferred value for $e^z$.  Consequently, it is usually simply written $e^z$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry but does your first line mean that the answer to my question is " it is true" ? If so, why then do you say that  "it is indeed not a result of applying the law of indices?" . Also what is the meaning of $\forall z\in\Bbb C^*$ in your second statement?

Comment: Yes, my 1st line means "it is true" (and can even be generalized to $a>0$ instead of $e,$ and $u,v\in\Bbb C$ instead of $\in i\Bbb R$), but not because of my second statement. And $\Bbb C^*$ is the set of non-zero complex numbers.